# How do I accept an answer from a sister site for a question I originally asked on Stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

[This Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025664/how-do-i-shorten-the-repository-url-using-svnssh-similar-to-svnserve-r) is the situation I am talking about... I'd like to accept the answer on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

They are separate sites. There  is no mechanism to accept an answer from another site.

If you discovered a good answer elsewhere (in this case Server Fault), I would post it as an answer to your question and accept it. You also need to give attribution to the original source.

Comment: Uhhh if the question get's migrated to SF he should associate his account and then it's his question, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, if the question belongs on SF, that makes more sense. I didn't know it was being migrated. That's more your department <grin>.

Comment: It's not being migrated... how do I start that process?  Good idea.

Comment: Ah I didn't bother to check whether it was or not. However, if it is kept alive on Stack Overflow, I believe the current policy is that it should be treated like a native question. So copy-paste the answer from SF and accept it.

Comment: Oh and in the future @Marcus, ask the question in one place and if it's in the wrong place, the community will move it for you.